# Improve Insert into table performance in sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-performance

There are a couple of things confusing me at this level.

I have a table with around 40 columns out of which atleast 35 are in where clause at different times in single execution of a procedure.

When these 35 columns are passed a value via stored procedure, the stored procedure call their respective inline TVF's which in turn call a common multiline TVF.

1. I need to know if I shall consider creating indexes for all these 35 columns (Though I have serious doubts if that can help, but please tell me I am wrong if it does. )
2. I am inserting data into a Temporary table . This insert goes on for number of parameters passed to stored procedure and execution plan shows it takes quite a considerable amount of time. Is there a way I can improve the performance here ?

The insert query looks like this :

```
   INSERT INTo #Temp2
 (RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage) 
SELECT RowNumber,@firstname,'firstname',PercentMatch,
@constVal,PercentMatch * @constVal FROM   dbo.MatchFirstName(@firstname)
```

:
Execution plan is attached :

[execution plan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxOpCNGSZCazeDdSUlN1WGFmaEE/view?usp=sharing)

Table with large number of columns is as follows :

```
create table Patients
(
Rowid int identity(1,1),
firstname nvarchar(20) not null,
middlename nvarchar(20),
lastname nvarchar(20)not null,
DOB Date,
SSN nvarchar(30), 
ZIP nvarchar(10),
[State] nvarchar(2),
City nvarchar(20),
StreetName nvarchar(20),
StreetType nvarchar(20),
BuildingNumber int,
Aptnumber nvarchar(10),
patientnickname nvarchar(20),
patientsMaidenlastname nvarchar(20), 
fathersFirstName nvarchar(20), 
fatherslastname nvarchar(20), 
mothersfirstname nvarchar(20), 
motherslastname nvarchar(20), 
mothersMaidenlastname nvarchar(20),
citizenship nvarchar(20),
nationality nvarchar(20), 
ethnicity nvarchar(20), 
race nvarchar(20), 
religion nvarchar(20),
primarylanguage nvarchar(20),
patientmrn nvarchar(30),
 hospitalname nvarchar(30), 
 Medicaidid nvarchar(10), 
 pcpnpi  nvarchar(10), 
 phonenumber nvarchar(15),
 email nvarchar(30),
 CreatedAt datetime default getdate(),
 ModifiedAt datetime DEFAULT getdate(),
 CreatedBy nvarchar(128) default SUSER_NAME(),
 ModifiedBy nvarchar(128) default SUSER_NAME()
);
```

Temporary table looks like this :

```
create table #Temp2
(
Rownumber int not null,
ValFromUser nvarchar(30),
ColumnName nvarchar(30),
ValFromFunc decimal(18, 4),
FuncWeight decimal(18, 4),
Percentage decimal(18, 4) not null,

);
```

ResultsStored table :

```
create table ResultsStored
(
Sno int identity(1,1),
SearchSerial int,
StringSearched varbinary(8000),
RowId int,
PercentMatch decimal(18,4),
CreatedAt datetime default getdate(),
ModifiedAt datetime default getdate(),
CreatedBy nvarchar(128) default SUSER_Name(),
ModifiedBy nvarchar(128) default SUSER_NAME(),
HashedKey binary(16) 
);
```

Comment: This will be difficult to answer without some knowledge of the table schema and the contents of the various functions.

Comment: @EricHauenstein: Updated question with details. please check

Comment: Start at splitting 'patients' table. The only point to have dozens of columns in a single table is to have a few rows (and not to use indexes at all).

Answer (score 0):

1. Indexes speed up (sometimes) SELECTs. But indexes slow down INSERTs (and also DELETEs, UPDATEs etc.). So it's a bad idea to have too many indexes.
2. Quite often SELECT is able to use only one index (or even zero). So all other 34 indexes are nothing of help. Keep only those ones your SELECTs really use.
3. As you say, you have about 40 columns in a table with at least 35 columns are being mentioned in *distinct* 'WHERE'-clauses. That is your table not just big, but, which is far worse, it has too many potential keys. It's a very bad design. You need to split it to several tables. Read about normalization.

Comment: Please check the Patients table. With the scenario I have , it does not make sense to split the patients table at all.

Comment: @Simran Why? How many rows do you have? How often do you INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE? If you need many indexes you have to split.

Comment: The Patients table will have may be millions of rows in it. Update and delete may not be very often but inserts are pretty often relatively.

Comment: @Simran Well, a single operation is usually no problem. Yet sometimes you need to operate on a whole db - backuping, deleting old data etc. Such queries will be dreadfully slow.

Comment: Point taken . But for the most part, I am doing select operation on Patients table. I somehow feel the most of the execution time is going into calling functions. Could you please check the execution plan and suggest the change in queries, if possible ?

Comment: @Simran I don't have MSStudio to read that xml beast. I can only guess that you tried to make a kind of 'swiss-army-knife'-query with a bunch of bound parameters, casing on each 'when is not null then'. As execution plan (similar to compiling) is produced only once, the optimizer couldn't choose the proper strategy (as it really depends upon input) and sticked to 'full-scanning anyway' plan. So it's always equally bad.